# Firebase persistence in swift 3

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3

As per firebase official documentation for swift we should use following line to enable persistence in iOS.

```
Firebase.defaultConfig().persistenceEnabled = true
```

But if we use the above line in swift 3.0 it gives error.

[image: Error image]

Any idea how to enable persistence in swift 3.0?

Comment: Can you write down whats the error?

Comment: Hey @NA000022, I have attached an image, please have a look.

Comment: Actually error suggests that defaultConfig method syntax has changed. Probably you have copied it . So remove the line and write it down by yourself. Auto Complete will suggest you the latest syntax.

Comment: Hey @NA000022 I am unable to find the correct line. Auto complete is not yielding any result :(

Comment: Yeah actually you are taking it wrong. @MGTLA suggested what is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 1):

In AppDelegate.swift

```
Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 1):

- In your AppDelegate.swift - `import FirebaseDatabase`
- Then first configure your Firebase Application by calling `FirebaseApp.configure()` in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method of your AppDelegate.swift.
- Below that write `Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true`.